# What happens when interrupt a thread that is blocked or sleeping?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, interrupted-exception

> Which of the following occurs after invoking the interrupt method on a
>   thread that is blocking due to a previous invocation of the join,
>   sleep or wait method?
>
> 1. The thread moves into the not-runnable state
> 2. The thread moves out of the not-runnable state
> 3. An interruptedException is thrown when thread moves into the running state
> 4. Calling Thread.interrupted after InterruptedException is thrown will return true
> 5. None of the above.

For answering the above question, I created the following programs.

**Program 1**

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            boolean interrupted = Thread.interrupted();
            System.out.println(interrupted);
            Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
            System.out.println("Current Thread ID : " + currentThread.getId());
            System.out.println("State : " + currentThread.getState());
            Thread t = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("runnable target"));
            System.out.println("Thread t not started yet : " + t.getState());
            System.out.println("Thread t not started yet : " + t.isAlive());
            System.out.println("T id : " + t.getId());

            Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("runnable target");
                        if (i == 5) {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

            });
            t2.start();
            System.out.println("T id : " + t2.getId());
            System.out.println("default priority : " + t2.getPriority());

            System.out.println("interrupting the main thread---");
            currentThread.interrupt();
            System.out.println("Current Thread ID : " + currentThread.getId());
            System.out.println("State : " + currentThread.getState());
            System.out.println("State : " + currentThread.isInterrupted());

            System.out.println("interrupting the t2 thread---");
            t2.interrupt();
            System.out.println("Current Thread ID : " + t2.getId());
            System.out.println("State : " + t2.getState());
            System.out.println("State : " + t2.isInterrupted());

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted Exception :" + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output of program 1:**

```
false
Current Thread ID : 1
State : RUNNABLE
Thread t not started yet : NEW
Thread t not started yet : false
T id : 10
T id : 11
default priority : 5
interrupting the main thread---
Current Thread ID : 1
State : RUNNABLE
State : true
interrupting the t2 thread---
Current Thread ID : 11
State : RUNNABLE
State : true
runnable target
runnable target
runnable target
runnable target
runnable target
runnable target
runnable target
runnable target
runnable target
Jan 12, 2018 3:36:43 PM javaapplication1.JavaApplication1 lambda$main$1
runnable target
SEVERE: null
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.lambda$main$1(JavaApplication1.java:27)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Program 2**

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            boolean interrupted = Thread.interrupted();
            System.out.println(interrupted);
            Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
            System.out.println("Current Thread ID : " + currentThread.getId());
            System.out.println("State : " + currentThread.getState());
            Thread t = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("runnable target"));
            System.out.println("Thread t not started yet : " + t.getState());
            System.out.println("Thread t not started yet : " + t.isAlive());
            System.out.println("T id : " + t.getId());

            Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("runnable target");
                        if (i == 5) {
                            System.out.println("t2 interrupted? "+Thread.interrupted());
                            System.out.println("State : "+currentThread.getState());
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

            });
            t2.start();
            System.out.println("T id : " + t2.getId());
            System.out.println("default priority : " + t2.getPriority());

            System.out.println("interrupting the main thread---");
            currentThread.interrupt();
            System.out.println("Current Thread ID : " + currentThread.getId());
            System.out.println("State : " + currentThread.getState());
            System.out.println("is interrupted : " + currentThread.isInterrupted());

            System.out.println("interrupting the t2 thread---");
            t2.interrupt();
            System.out.println("Current Thread ID : " + t2.getId());
            System.out.println("State : " + t2.getState());
            System.out.println("is interrupted : " + t2.isInterrupted());

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted Exception :" + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output of program 2:**

```
false
Current Thread ID : 1
State : RUNNABLE
Thread t not started yet : NEW
Thread t not started yet : false
T id : 10
T id : 11
default priority : 5
interrupting the main thread---
Current Thread ID : 1
State : RUNNABLE
State : true
interrupting the t2 thread---
Current Thread ID : 11
State : RUNNABLE
is interrupted : true
runnable target
runnable target
runnable target
runnable target
runnable target
runnable target
t2 interrupted? true
is interrupted : TERMINATED
runnable target
runnable target
runnable target
runnable target
```

I selected option 1 and 3 because,

1. The state is terminated in the program 2.
2. the state of t2 is RUNNABLE in program 1 and the sleep interrupting  exception is thrown respectively.

If the state of t2 is TERMINATED, **how did "runnable target" get printed 4 times** at the end? shouldn't the thread stop running if it's state is TERMINATED?

Comment: I think because thread 't' doesn't throw InterruptedException. You have three threads running here,only two of them (I believe) invoke the necessary methods to throw an InteruptedException. From [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) - 'If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long), or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(), join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an InterruptedException.'

Comment: @CowboyFarnz thanks for your comment but only two threads are running. The main thread and t2.. pl note that i hv not invoked the start method of the thread object t

Comment: @CowboyFarnz yeah i referred the API after posting the question. It doesnt say anything abt the state the thread goes to

Comment: it throws an InterruptedException, which clearsthe thread's interrupted status ('then its interrupt status will be cleared' - so resets it) but the thread will continue to run, that is the expected behaviour because of the way it is desinged (which I agree is a flaw). Try breaking out of your for loop and test the behaviour.

Comment: How is it that your code is printing "is interrupted : TERMINATED" when the print statement for that line only prints a boolean?  Regardless I ran the second code snippet and was not able to make it show TERMINATED for any state even after several runs.